# Reproducing stats::biplot with ggplot2::autoplot from ggfortify R package

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggfortify

I'm trying to reproduce the following `stats::biplot` plot with `ggplot2::autoplot` from `ggfortify` `R` package.

```
biplot(prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE))
```

[image]

Here is my `ggplot2::autoplot` code from `ggfortify` `R` package with its output.

```
devtools::install_github("sinhrks/ggfortify")
 library(ggfortify)
ggplot2::autoplot(stats::prcomp(USArrests, scale=TRUE), label = TRUE, loadings.label = TRUE)
```

[image]

**Questions**

1. Why the two plots are different? How to reproduce the base plot?
2. How to add labels as shown in base plot?

Comment: Please provide some data so we can tackle this.

Comment: @lawyeR: USArrests comes with R.

Comment: Sorry, I should have know that.  Maybe edit your question so that others know that also.  :)

Comment: Just posted what I think is  a more accurate answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for using the package. The issue is depending on {dplyr} version, and being fixed in {ggfortify}. Could you update the package and then try?

I've attached the result after the fix to below link:

https://github.com/sinhrks/ggfortify/pull/21

Comment: Excellent work and thanks for fixing the bug. Why the scales of two graphs are different? Any thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

To recreate this plot in `ggplot2`, you simply have to extract the data you need from the `prcomp` object.  In this case you are plotting the original data as well as the variable rotation loadings, so you need two data frames.

Try this:

```
x <- prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE)
z1 <- data.frame(State = rownames(x$x), x$x[, 1:2])
z2 <- data.frame(State = rownames(x$rotation), x$rotation[, 1:2])

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(z1, aes(PC1, PC2, label=State)) + 
  geom_text(size=3) +
  geom_segment(data=z2, aes(PC1, PC2, xend=0, yend=0), col="red") +
  geom_text(data=z2, aes(PC1, PC2, label=State), col="red") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: (+1): Thanks @Andrie for your answer. sinhrks has fixed the bug in ggfortify. But still the scales of two graphs are different. Any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Autoplot simulates the behaviour/scaling you get with `biplot.prcomp` option `pc.biplot = TRUE` :

```
devtools::install_github("sinhrks/ggfortify")
 library(ggfortify)
ggplot2::autoplot(stats::prcomp(USArrests, scale=TRUE), label = TRUE, loadings.label = TRUE)
```

[image]

```
biplot(prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE), pc.biplot = TRUE)
```

[image]

It then produces the "principal component biplot" of Gabriel (1971), whereby observations are scaled up by sqrt(n) and variables scaled down by sqrt(n). The inner products between variables then approximate covariances and distances between observations approximate Mahalanobis distance. Normally this is what you want anyway, see also the detailed expanation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141085/positioning-the-arrows-on-a-pca-biplot).

[ggord](https://github.com/fawda123/ggord) btw is also a nice package for making biplots, as is [ggbiplot](https://github.com/vqv/ggbiplot).

PS: the answer flagged above as correct is not really the correct one I believe.